# Ruby format string with variable inside quotes

Tags: ruby, string, formatting, string-formatting, string-interpolation

If I do

```
template_string = "class=btn submit-button %<additional_classes>"
format(template_string, additional_classes: 'some-class')
```

it works. However, if I do

```
template_string = "class='btn submit-button %<additional_classes>'"
format(template_string, additional_classes: 'some-class')
```

it fails, giving

```
ArgumentError:
  malformed format string - %'
```

(Notice the quotation marks surrounding the classes in the second template_string - this is the only difference between the two blocks of Ruby code). How do I make it work? In other words, how do I produce the following?

> class='btn submit-button some-class'

I don't believe that I can just use interpolation, because sometimes I need to pass in other variables. In other words, I can't do

```
additional_classes = 'some-class'
"class='btn submit-button #{additional_classes}'"
```

because sometimes I want to reuse the same string "template" but pass in other variables, to produce strings such as the following:

> class='btn submit-button some-other-class'

or

> class='btn submit-button some-third-class'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-format):

> **format(format_string [, arguments...] ) → string**
>   [...]
>   For more complex formatting, Ruby supports a reference by name. `%<name>s` style uses format style, but `%{name}` style doesn't.

The documentation isn't as clear as it could be but when you use the `%<...>` form, it is expecting to see `%<name>s` where `name` is the hash key and `s` is the format type: `s` for string, `d` for number, ... If you say:

```
%<additional_classes>'
```

then `format` will try to interpret `'` as a type when there is no such type specifier so you get an `ArgumentError` because the format string is malformed.

You probably want to use the `%{...}` form instead:

```
template_string = "class='btn submit-button %{additional_classes}'"
#--------------------------------------------^------------------^
```

Answer (score 2):

Your format string is missing the [field type specifier](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-format). The field type specifier is mandatory in a format string.

It is not clear to me why the first example does not raise an error, since the mandatory field type specifier is missing. It could be a bug, or I am completely misreading the documentation.

However, it is not clear to me why you consider this example to work:

```
template_string = "class=btn submit-button %<additional_classes>"
format(template_string, additional_classes: 'some-class')
#=> 'class=btn submit-button %'
#                            ↑
```

As you can see, the `%` is not interpreted as the part of a format string but as a literal `%`. I would consider this a bug, it should raise an error, just like the second example does.

In the second example, you can clearly see the problem:

```
ArgumentError: malformed format string - %'
                                          ↑
```

Since a format string must have a field type specifier, and the only character after the `%` (except the field name) is `'`, this is interpreted as the field type specifier. And since `'` is not a legal field type, `format` raises an error in which it explicitly tells you that it interpreted the `'` as part of the format string.

Since you want to format strings, you should use the `s` (string) field type specifier:

```
template_string = "class=btn 'submit-button %<additional_classes>s'"
#                                                                ↑

format(template_string, additional_classes: 'some-class')
#=> "class=btn 'submit-button some-class'"
#                             ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
```

Alternatively, you can use the `%{}` form:

```
template_string = "class=btn 'submit-button %{additional_classes}'"
#                                            ↑                  ↑

format(template_string, additional_classes: 'some-class')
#=> "class=btn 'submit-button some-class'"
#                             ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
```